# Changes in state by different class (not react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 2 classes

One is react component, second is standard class (validation).

In Validation class is added as element in react state.

```
state.formValidator = new FormValidation({id: 'install'});
   this.setState(state);
```

FormValidation class as properties has class for Input valdiation. When some input is update, then also FormValidation isValid property is update.

And in my react component I can see it. For example, When I added event on input element. After update I was call function to display state.formValidator

isValid property value is correct. But I can't force on react automatically detect this change.

When

```
this.state.formValidator.isValid
```

value is changing by other class/component I can't detect this change in my React component.

Methods componentWillUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps are silence.

How can I force update this component?

I know that I can add for each input event onUpdate and then update my React component. But better way for be would be use it without trigger for each input.

Does it possible?

Answer (score 0):

React checks state changes by simple `===` checks. Therefore, if you just change a property within an object in the state, it won't rerender, because objects compare by reference equality, and changing a property within the object does not change its reference ID.

For this reason, it is in general not a good idea to have objects in your state - your state should be flat.

You can force your component to render when a certain condition happens by calling [`this.forceUpdate()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) from your component, but this is discouraged unless sorely needed.

A second option would be to make your component's rendering state depend on your `formValidator.isValid` property, or to have your `formValidator` be kept elsewhere and only the `isValid` property be copied to your state.